# MySQL trigger error 1064 when enclosing if else with multiple statements

Tags: mysql, triggers

I'm trying to do a simple trigger that check two columns are null if a third column has a specific value.

```
DELIMITER |
CREATE TRIGGER after_insert_ping AFTER INSERT
ON ping FOR EACH ROW
    BEGIN
        IF NEW.protocol_id = 'sip' THEN
            BEGIN
                IF NEW.sip_account_name IS NULL THEN
                    SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000' SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'some error';
                ELSE IF NEW.is_sip_register_autotest_enabled IS NULL THEN
                    SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45001' SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'some error';
                END IF;
            END;
        ELSE
            BEGIN
                IF NEW.sip_account_name IS NOT NULL THEN
                    SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45002' SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'some error';
                ELSE IF NEW.is_sip_register_autotest_enabled IS NOT NULL THEN
                    SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45003' SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'some error';
                END IF;
            END;
        END IF;
    END |
```

I got this :

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ';
ELSE
BEGIN
    IF NEW.sip_account_name IS NOT NULL
    THEN
      ' at line 13
```

I checked MySQL if syntax here : https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/if.html

I read we need to enclose our multiple statements between BEGIN and END and i tried to do so.

Any idea why do I have this error when compiling the trigger ?

Comment: Else if should probably be elseif

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a difference in `ELSE IF` and `ELSEIF` usage.

`ELSE IF` need to be closed explicitly by `END IF`.
Here `IF` after *space* `ELSE` is treated as a new `IF` code block.

Where as `ELSEIF` is closed by its parent `IF`.

Either you change `ELSE IF` to `ELSEIF` in your statements, or
add `END IF` to the inner `IF` block.

**Read Documentation**:

- [**IF Syntax**](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/if.html)

> ```
> IF search_condition THEN statement_list
>     [ELSEIF search_condition THEN statement_list] ...
>     [ELSE statement_list]
> END IF
> ```

Comment: The devil's in the details. I think i could spend hours because i wasn't in the right direction. Thank you very much.